# Fancybox not animating correctly with jQuery.Animate-Enhanced

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I'm trying to use Fancybox 2.1.3 on this new website I'm working on : http://egelect.com/2013/eg-electrique-maitre-electricien.php

The problem is that the origine of the Fancybox animation is not the center of the screen, as it should be. I'm using Fancybox out-of-the-box specs.

I know that it's because of jQuery.Animate-Enhanced.min.js (v0.99), since when I comment out this .js, Fancybox behaves correclty.

Tested on Chrome, FF, and IE9.

Anyone as a clue what I should be looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with Fancybox 1.3, when initially opening up fancybox.  However, if you noticed - if you resize the browser - it will center itself.

I haven't had time to find a solution but I did manage to find that in the $.fancybox.center function - where's it calling the animate function - after finishing, the calculation for t webkit animation pretty much ended up negating the top and left position of the fancybox.  If you inspect the element after the animation, you will see this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, add to reposition function (into the jquery.fancybox.js script) a toggle to avoidCSSTransitions when positioning the fancybox.

I really don't like much this solution, but it works.

My code:

```
    reposition: function(e, onlyAbsolute) {
        var current = F.current,
                wrap = current ? current.wrap : null,
                pos;

        if (wrap) {
            pos = F._getPosition(onlyAbsolute);

            if (e && e.type === 'scroll') {
                delete pos.position;

                wrap.stop(true, true).animate(pos, {avoidCSSTransitions:true}, 200);

            } else {
                $.toggleDisabledByDefault();
                wrap.css(pos);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $.toggleDisabledByDefault();
                },1);
                current.pos = $.extend({}, current.dim, pos);
            }
        }
    },
```